# Django Formset Posting but formset is never valid

Tags: django, django-forms, formset

I have created a Formset based on modelformset_factory and an existing Form in my view and pass it a queryset of objects to edit. These render correctly on the view but whenever I try and confirm, it does not save. Printing the statement (print(formset.is_valid()) I see that this is what is stopping the formset saving.

How does one correctly pass existing queryset to a formset to edit?

**Forms.py**

```
class RSVPForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Invite
        fields = ['guest_name', 'plus_one', 'dietry_requirements', 'rsvp_attendance']
```

**Views.py**

```
def view_rsvp_create(request, event_id, guest_id):

    event = get_object_or_404(Event, id=event_id) 
    guest = get_object_or_404(Guest, id=guest_id) 
    invites = Invite.objects.filter(event=event, guest=guest)

    RSVPFormset = modelformset_factory(Invite, form=RSVPForm, extra=0)
    formset = RSVPFormset(queryset=invites)

    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if formset.is_valid():
            print('okey')

            formset.save()
            return redirect('view_rsvp_overview', name = guest.wedding.subdomain, code = guest.code)

    data = {'formset': formset, 'guest': guest, 'wedding': event.wedding, 'invites':invites}
    template='experience/rsvp-create.html'
    return render(request, template, data)
```

**update.html**

```
...
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %} {{ formset | crispy }}
<button type="submit" class="btn">{% trans "Confirm RSVP" %}</button>
</form>
...
```

Comment: what is form.errors ?

Comment: @NishantNawarkhede formset.errors is blank

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by changing the if statement around if `request.method == 'POST':`

to the following:

```
formset = RSVPFormset(request.POST or None, queryset=invites)
```